# Running Telethon on Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, flask, telegram, telethon

I'm trying to make an application which would run permanently (i.e. send me information every minute to my Telethon account), and figured out the best way to do so would be through hosting it on heroku. I'm also using Flask - and am a beginner in all three tools. 
This is what I have:

```
from twx.botapi import TelegramBot, ReplyKeyboardMarkup
from telethon import TelegramClient
from telethon.tl.types.input_peer_chat import InputPeerChat
import time
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect

app = Flask(__name__)
chat_id = 40398****
api_id = '10****'
api_hash = 'bae9b**********************'

client = TelegramClient('ID_1', api_id=api_id, api_hash=api_hash)
client.connect()
chat = InputPeerChat(chat_id)

@app.route('/')
def starting_page():
    global client

    if not client.is_user_authorized():
        client.send_code_request('+1234567890') # this is a phone number

    return render_template('index.html', author=author)
.
.
.
#if __name__ == '__main__': # this seems to run automatically on heroku so I commented it out
#    app.run()
```

The thing is that this code creates two errors and I don't understand why.
1.  telethon.errors.rpc_errors_303.PhoneMigrateError: (PhoneMigrateError(...), 'The phone number a user is tryin use for authorization is associated with DC 4.')
2. telethon.errors.rpc_errors_420.FloodWaitError: (FloodWaitError(...), 'A wait of 68533 seconds is required')

I have no idea how to resolve both of these, especially since the script works when run independently, and through a local server. The problem is when trying to bring in heroku.

Thanks!

Full error listing:

```
2017-08-19T13:00:39.644337+00:00 app[web.1]: [2017-08-19 13:00:39,641] ERROR in app: Exception on / [GET]
2017-08-19T13:00:39.644346+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2017-08-19T13:00:39.644349+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/telethon/telegram_client.py", line 205, in invoke
2017-08-19T13:00:39.644350+00:00 app[web.1]:     request, updates=updates
2017-08-19T13:00:39.644351+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/telethon/telegram_bare_client.py", line 276, in invo
2017-08-19T13:00:39.644352+00:00 app[web.1]:     self._sender.receive(request, updates=updates)
2017-08-19T13:00:39.644352+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/telethon/network/mtproto_sender.py", line 109, in ree
2017-08-19T13:00:39.644354+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/telethon/network/mtproto_sender.py", line 207, in _pss_msg
2017-08-19T13:00:39.644354+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self._handle_rpc_result(msg_id, sequence, reader)
2017-08-19T13:00:39.644353+00:00 app[web.1]:     remote_msg_id, remote_seq, reader, updates)
2017-08-19T13:00:39.644356+00:00 app[web.1]:     raise error
2017-08-19T13:00:39.644357+00:00 app[web.1]: telethon.errors.rpc_errors_303.PhoneMigrateError: (PhoneMigrateError(...), 'The phone number a user is tryin use for authorization is associated with DC 4.')
2017-08-19T13:00:39.644358+00:00 app[web.1]:
2017-08-19T13:00:39.644355+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/telethon/network/mtproto_sender.py", line 355, in _he_rpc_result
2017-08-19T13:00:39.644359+00:00 app[web.1]: During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
2017-08-19T13:00:39.644359+00:00 app[web.1]:
2017-08-19T13:00:39.644360+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2017-08-19T13:00:39.644360+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
2017-08-19T13:00:39.644361+00:00 app[web.1]:     response = self.full_dispatch_request()
2017-08-19T13:00:39.644362+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
2017-08-19T13:00:39.644362+00:00 app[web.1]:     rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
2017-08-19T13:00:39.644363+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
2017-08-19T13:00:39.644363+00:00 app[web.1]:     reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
2017-08-19T13:00:39.644364+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
2017-08-19T13:00:39.644365+00:00 app[web.1]:     raise value
2017-08-19T13:00:39.644365+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
2017-08-19T13:00:39.644366+00:00 app[web.1]:     rv = self.dispatch_request()
2017-08-19T13:00:39.644367+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
2017-08-19T13:00:39.644367+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
2017-08-19T13:00:39.644368+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/telegram_bot_working.py", line 33, in starting_page
2017-08-19T13:00:39.644368+00:00 app[web.1]:     client.send_code_request('+1234567890')
2017-08-19T13:00:39.644369+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/telethon/telegram_client.py", line 259, in send_codeuest
2017-08-19T13:00:39.644370+00:00 app[web.1]:     SendCodeRequest(phone_number, self.api_id, self.api_hash))
2017-08-19T13:00:39.644370+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/telethon/telegram_client.py", line 222, in invoke
2017-08-19T13:00:39.644371+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.invoke(request)
2017-08-19T13:00:39.644372+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/telethon/telegram_client.py", line 205, in invoke
2017-08-19T13:00:39.644372+00:00 app[web.1]:     request, updates=updates
2017-08-19T13:00:39.644373+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/telethon/telegram_bare_client.py", line 276, in invo
2017-08-19T13:00:39.644374+00:00 app[web.1]:     self._sender.receive(request, updates=updates)
2017-08-19T13:00:39.644375+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/telethon/network/mtproto_sender.py", line 109, in ree
2017-08-19T13:00:39.644375+00:00 app[web.1]:     remote_msg_id, remote_seq, reader, updates)
2017-08-19T13:00:39.644376+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/telethon/network/mtproto_sender.py", line 207, in _pss_msg
2017-08-19T13:00:39.644376+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self._handle_rpc_result(msg_id, sequence, reader)
2017-08-19T13:00:39.644377+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/telethon/network/mtproto_sender.py", line 355, in _he_rpc_result
2017-08-19T13:00:39.644378+00:00 app[web.1]:     raise error
2017-08-19T13:00:39.644383+00:00 app[web.1]: telethon.errors.rpc_errors_420.FloodWaitError: (FloodWaitError(...), 'A wait of 68533 seconds is required.')
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought this way of running it on Heroku was a bit messy. Instead I've created an [AlchemySession](http://telethon.readthedocs.io/en/latest/extra/advanced-usage/sessions.html#using-alchemysession) so that Telethon stores its data into the Heroku Postgres database.

You can either retrieve the Heroku `DATABASE_URL` or paste it together yourself and pass that into the `AlchemySessionContainer`. There was a bug that prevented this from working but that has just been fixed.